# Tuple without having to use as keyword

Tags: typescript

I often find my self in the situation where I have an array, which I *know* is actually a tuple - but typescript can't always figure it out. I end up having to use `as` to assert the type, which isn't ideal.

Maybe this is duplicate - but I haven't yet found anything to get around this.

Here's an example:

```js
const f = (x: [string, string]) => x.map(s => s.toUpperCase());
```

In the example above, `f` returns an `string[]` - when we ought to be able to determine that this is `[string, string]`. Clearly we can just do:

```js
const f = (x: [string, string]) => x.map(s => s.toUpperCase()) as [string, string];
```

I'd like to be able to do that without using `as` - is it possible?

Comment: There's no way to get around this, that's why you haven't found a way to get around this :). `map` is defined as returning an array, not a tuple. Thus, you need the `as`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey A good point! Really I suppose the root of the problem is that 'tuples' are actually arrays in typescript; really by using an array method, I'm dumping the tuple-ness out of the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible if you augment the standard library types.

The default definition for `Array#map` has no recollection of the length of your array. However, you can make it work with tuples by introducing another overload. Such an overload needs to infer the length of your tuple.

**Required overload**

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    map<U>(this: T[] | [T], callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: this) => U, thisArg?: any): {
      [index in keyof this]: U
    };
  }
}
```

This technique uses [mapped tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays).

**Usage**

`Array#map` takes into account the length of your tuple now.

```
/**
 * f :: [string, string] => [string, string]
 */
const f = (x: [string, string]) => x.map(s => s.toUpperCase());

/**
 * f :: [string, string, string] => [string, string, string]
 */
const g = (x: [string, string, string]) => x.map(s => s.toUpperCase())

/**
 * f :: [string, string, string] => [number, number, number]
 */
const h = (x: [string, string, string]) => x.map(s => s.length)
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeAoe8AlgHYAuIMAZlGAgIIwxQCeAPACoB8O+B8AtlAAOrAKqcAFKQAWhAM4AueOwDaAXXgAfeCvZqANPDCYIGMAGtKxJRIBumAK4gl7QyVAAPJcQf80FQ1gmZiUZeQBKeABeblFDMLkGRAB+JShiZnClPD4+FXcQDyJieHMQZhRKeAS1JVFeAgBfAG5eRtx23AB6ACoe-B74KoUlFTlSGBJEQ3HJ4kQNGJ1ZqZmJqbUBrtwwFGJxoej4CS9l9fm1uYXIpY8AOkEhCTlo7jk70hRRISEKAGEoHIQBJwuFWt0+gNDiMzldLqt4Ct5otuGNztNEej4citjs9gdEEcTqMkRjSdjrq94PdHs8qe9Pt9fjAAUCQeFcBD+vBBsMSVjMXDBRsqSofH4AvBxf4YIZpRRNjztrt9qR4NIiac0ULycLkTduDThHSlu8ICB5jIObhCkIUDA1dhGkA)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd put an answer here to collate some thoughts/solutions, and see whether it helps to reach a 'good' solution.

Tuples in Typescript are actually just arrays - and in some ways that's great because one of the things we want from tuples is to be able to access them by an index - as they are in python, for instance, or C# (granted, in C# we do this with `ItemN`).

Given that our tuples here are just arrays, we *can* use array methods. But what ought those array methods return? If typescript brought along some concept of the size of the array, then we can know which methods manipulate the size of the array and which don't. `map` for instance, is guaranteed *not* to change the size of the array, and so we can know that an array of fixed size n will always return an array of size n - though the types may be changed.

Typescript doesn't do this, though. Array methods for an array `T[]` just returns `T[]`. So what can we do to solve the problem? We can take only the parts of array that we actually want:

```js
type Tuple2<T> = Pick<T[], 0 | 1>

const x: Tuple2<number> = [1, 2];

x.map(); // type error
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=23&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhATAHhgPigXigBQEsBjAawwG0BdAGigAYoAfKARkwFgAob4gewB2AZ2BQAHgC5YCZOgFwAtgCMIAJ2x4KrOiioBubtzEA6BQEMwACgCUeqAHp7UUJChrVfVUA)

Or we could have a function that asserts a pair:

```js
const assertAsPair = <A, B, C>(x: [A, B, ...C[]]) => [x[0], x[1]];
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=67&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhCBTATlAghACnAlimAXhgB50AaGAIUoGEA+ACgA8AuGAbQusoDp-aHALpCAlEXqdmHAAxDK0gIwiA3EA)

The issue here is that `assertAsPair` returns the type (A | B)[]. Better than `[A, B, ...C[]]`, but really not quite what we wanted.

So far it doesn't seem possible to define tuples without assertions. Here's hoping it will be possible in the future!